# Authenticated user does not have permission to access data stored in Firebase

Tags: firebase, firebase-security, firebasesimplelogin

I have an authenticated user, which is given authentication through using `FirebaseSimpleLogin`. This user has the token:

```
'user':{
    email: "myemail@internets.com",
    firebaseAuthToken: SOME TOKEN,
    "id: "4",
    isTemporaryPassword: true,
    md5_hash: "aHash123",
    provider: "password",
    uid: "simplelogin:4"
    }
```

I have given the authenticated user read permission under the 'rules and security' tab in firebase using:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "SOME DATA": {
      ".read": "auth.email == 'myemail@internets.com'", 
      ".write": true
    }
  }
}
```

However, when it comes to accessing the data, I get the error:

```
Error: permission_denied: Client doesn't have permission to access the desired data.
```

Am I missing something fundamental as to why I do not have read permission?

Comment: I am a moron. This approach was a-okay.
In the rules: "SOME DATA" was actually meant to be "SOMEDATA". Check those URLs people!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the security rules section of firebase, I had made an error.

```
{
  "rules": {
    "SOMEDATA": { //NOTE: removal of space character
      ".read": "auth.email == 'myemail@internets.com'", 
      ".write": true
    }
  }
}
```

Lesson learnt: be very specific with rules, and always follow some convention.

Answer (score 1):

Try This and Like-Up if its worked:

```
service firebase.storage {
  match /b/<url data>/o {
    match /{allPaths=**} {
      allow read, write: if true;
    }
  }
}
```